# How to connect mongodb cluster from mongodb compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I created a free mongodb cluster. I created a user,set the connection to the mongodb compass, copied the connection string and then opened my mongodb compass .Pasted the copied string there,set the password and then pressed connect.It processes for a while and then throws a error of

```
connection <monitor> to 15.207.225.15:27017 closed.
```

Can someone solve it out .

Answer (score 2):

I deleted previous IP address from network access list and added it again.

Then I tried db connection from compass and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your IP address to the IP access list before you can connect to your cluster. Follow the [guide](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/ip-access-list/).

Answer (score 1):

add a new Ip address -> network access menu -> add a new IP as 'access from anywhere' and may work

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and this is how I solved it.

Delete the project and create a new one with the same credentials used before (if you prefer) and try connecting back again.

Note:  make sure to remember your password.

Answer (score 0):

just add a new Ip address just click on network access edit add your current IP address and you should be able to connect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).